# How to replace similar objects using Duplikate Linked?

Tags: gpu, instances

I have a model of a building. I have created it in Sketchup, imported to Blender as a OBJ file. It has a lot of similar objects, like AC or windows.
[image]

I want to make this model lighter using Blender function Duplicate linked. I heard it lowers GPU load. But I have a problem to separate similar objects. For example when I use seperate by loose parts it will break AC into many pieces, It will create problem to select similar objects.
[image].

Is it possible to select similar objects at once and replace them  with linked duplicates?

Comment: Hello, please don't use capitals for your title. To replace several objects with a linked duplication, select all these objects, shift select the object that has the mesh you want to link, and Ctrl L > Link Object Data

Comment: Hi, Sarvar Shodiyev. I hope you don't mind my edit.

Comment: @moonboots Hi, is there easier way of selecting hundreds of similar objects? Did you read my question at all?

Comment: Not that I know  :/